# How do I ban special characters in a field entry?

Tags: validation, cakephp, sanitization

http://u.neighborrow.com/items/recent/ for this page I obviously want to ban links and other spam.

The data is entered on this page http://u.neighborrow.com/items/create/

Comment: Edited the answer below (validation is also a good way ;])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the best way to do this is store inserted items the way they were added, and sanitize them while outputting. To do this you can use a CakePHP core library called [Sanitize](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1183/Data-Sanitization). Methods html and clean should you read.

Another option is data validation. Core rule for [alphaNumeric](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1153/alphaNumeric) or a [custom rule](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1179/Custom-Validation-Rules).

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1185/html html is the one i want to use for now - where do i inject it in the code

Comment: like that in the view: `echo Sanitize::html($data['Item']['field'], array('remove' => true));`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it...there are countless others...

Add this javascript to your page:

function alphanum(e) {
var k;
document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
return ((k > 47 && k < 58) || (k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k==13);
}

In your html control, tie it to onkeypress like this:

onkeypress="return alphanum(event)"

Answer (score 0):

preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9\s$]/i',  $this->data['Item']['item'])

if any spl chars are there then 1 will be returned.. else 0